# Merge objects containing array

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I merge two objects containing array and other fields using lodash?

For example,

```
obj1 = {
    name: "abc",
    hobbies: ["reading","cricket"]
}
obj2 = {
    name: "abc2",
    hobbies: ["reading","hockey"]
}
_.merge(obj1, obj2)

// output
{
    name: "abc2",
    hobbies: ["reading","hockey"]
}
```

this returns an object after merging obj1 into obj2 but without merging the hobbies.

Comment: So, you want to overwrite `name` with `obj2`, but *not* overwrite `hobbies`?

Comment: I want hobbies to be merged(union).

Comment: Your output is just the same as `obj2`.  I'm a little confused at the result you want.

Comment: Name is correct. I want hobbies to be reading, cricket, hockey

Comment: `_.merge` isn't part of underscore.js.  Where are you getting that from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) doesn't have a `_.merge` function so I'm assuming you're using [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#merge). If that's the case, you can use the `callback` parameter to do what you want

```
var obj1 = { name: 'abc', hobbies: ['reading', 'cricket'] };
var obj2 = { name: 'def', hobbies: ['reading', 'hockey'] };

var output = _.merge(obj1, obj2, function(a,b) {
    return _.isArray(a) ? _.union(a,b) : undefined;
} );
console.log( output );

// output

{ name: 'def', hobbies: ['reading', 'cricket', 'hockey'] }
```

#### EDIT

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5ynkL3u/).